# Can't handle react spinner loading using useState

Tags: reactjs, spinner, use-state

I use a function component, so i have to use UseState to handle component states.
I'm trying to show a spinner when loading data with axios :

```
import { Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MandatesPage = props => {

  const [mandates, setMandates] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); //  to handle spinner hide show

   useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);  // here loading is true
    console.log(loading)
    axios
        .get(`${config.api}/mandates`)
        .then(response => response.data["hydra:member"],setLoading(false)) // here loading is false
        .then(data => setMandates(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response));
}, []);

 ...
  if (loading) return
    return (
        <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
    );
}

return (
   .....  // return the other logic of my app
 )

}
```

my problem is the spinner is not shown and i put console.log(loading) after setLoading(true) but i got false value.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `loading` is still false, because the setting is async and will only be true on the next render.

For the next render, the loading spinner will be returned, since loading will be true than.
If the axios calls needs short than 16 - 32ms, which is the normal frame for each render in react, the loading spinner will not be shown, because loading will already be set back to false.

Comment: so when i should setloading false again to show the spinner?

Comment: No its fine to set it to false once the call is done, but you do not need s spinner if you do not have to wait, right?

Comment: okay , thanks, i will try the some good with a big number of data

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying a asynchronous operation in a synchronous way. You should be holding until your API response gets back, something more like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchMyAPI() {
    let url = 'http://something/';
    let config = {};
    const response = await myFetch(url);
    console.log(response);
  }  

  fetchMyAPI();
}, []);
```

Applying to your example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  async function fetchOnAxios() {
   const response = await axios.get(`${config.api}/mandates`)
    // Down below inside this function
    // you can set the loading based on the response
  }
  fetchOnAxios()
}, []);
```

I deeply recommend [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) for further reading, it has examples and everything.

Comment: thank you for your question, but i don't understand the difference between your 2 codes please

Comment: There is no difference, the first one is just an example of how you should handle fetching data inside a `useEffect` hook. The second one is applying the same logic to your code. After `response` is set you can do any logic you did with `.then` and `.catch`

Comment: If you want to have a good understanding on the issue you're trying to solve, read the linked article at the bottom of my answer.